# css off-center border for an image

Tags: css

I've got a fairly simple `CSS` where I want to display a border slightly off center to the right and bottom, I'm using the pseudo-selector `:after` to display it.

The problem i'm having is that the border it's displaying is running to the height of the outer `div` that's dictated by the amount of text displayed, rather than the `img` itself (which is what I want it to do).

If I put another `div` inside to wrap around the image it doesn't seem to make a difference, the same if I make the pseudo-selector after the image and convert the image to a block.

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jimbeeer/optqra64/4/) to show all you lovely smart people that might be able to help me!

Comment: _“If I put another div inside to wrap around the image it doesn't seem to make a difference”_ - that’s because that div does not actually wrap around the image taking its dimensions – but is as high as your whole outer container, because that has `display: grid;`

Comment: Also, please edit your question - code relevant to your problem belongs _directly_ into your question, in text form and properly formatted (or as a snippet), not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: You’d need to wrap `.projectimage` into an additional div, so that _that_ becomes the grid item that takes full height, and the `.projectimage` can then gets is height from the image it contains.

Comment: Oh my word, you're absolutely correct! If you put that as an answer rather than a comment, I'll give you the green flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I put another div inside to wrap around the image it doesn't seem to make a difference

That’s because that div does not actually wrap around the image taking its dimensions – but is as high as your whole outer container, because that has `display: grid`

You’d need to wrap `.projectimage` into an additional div, so that *that* becomes the grid item that takes full height, and the `.projectimage` element can then gets is height from the image it contains.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.project {
  width: 60%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.projectimage {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.projectimage img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.projectcontentleft {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.projectimage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.projectimage:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(214, 23, 71, 0.07);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 300ms linear 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="project">
    <div class="projectcontentleft">
      <h3><strong>Header</strong></h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <h3><strong>Appeals</strong></h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="projectimage-holder">
      <div class="projectimage">
        <img src="http://www.bbbhire.co.uk/images/services2.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: This is also a perfectly acceptable answer but misorude was 4 minutes quicker with a solution in the comments so i should really give them the tick.

Comment: @jimbeeer if you see the time i had posted the answer 1st then he posted it. please check the time

Comment: They posted the correct answer in the comments 4 minutes before you posted your answer. I suggested they posted their comment as the answer, then you posted your answer. I checked this very carefully before I awarded the tick.